# recyclerView different spacing between items using scale

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, layoutparams

Horizontal **recyclerView** (**DiscreteScrollView** library) with scaling set to 50% between selected view and others doesn't keep spacing the same. Example below shows that spacing between 1/2 and 4/5 are more spacious than views next to currently selected item on center. It happens gradually by scrolling, for an example going from item 3 to item 2 will be moving item 3/4 apart from each other when onScroll is happening.

[spacing between items example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EmGcz.jpg)
I Thought about checking the current width of view when onScroll is happening and programatically reduce the left/right margin by applying new layout params so the space would stay the same.

Trying:

```
override fun onScroll(
        scrollPosition: Float,
        currentPosition: Int,
        newPosition: Int,
        currentHolder: CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder?,
        newCurrent: CurrencyAdapter.ViewHolder?
    ) {
            val layoutParams  = currentHolder.layout.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
        }
    }
```

produces

```
ClassCastException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
```

**1. Is it possible to manipulate layoutParams from within viewHolder?**

**2. Are there any other options to set fixed spacing?**

**EDIT:**
adding DividerItemDecoration shows better where the problem is coming from:
[DividerItemDecoration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlNvj.jpg)

**3. Is ItemDecoration the right direction for fixing the issue then?**

Comment: have you tried using padding in your items?

Comment: space is changing gradually when scrolling is happening so using padding as a constant value won't fix the issue

Comment: try to use `DividerItemDecoration`

Comment: @Sergey Thanks Sergey for the suggestion, actually applying simple DividerItemDecoration shown very well where are these bounderies coming from. Can You take a look at added image snapshot and suggest if this is the right direction?